# Linq ThenBy Possibly Null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sort a view model binding on multiple properties. The problem is that the second property might be null, and I get a null reference exception.

```
return this.People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Car.Name)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Pet.Name);
```

What if Pet is null? How do I still do a ThenBy sort by Pet.Name?

Comment: How do want to order null-pets, first or last?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should return null Pets before non-null Pets.

```
return this.People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Car.Name)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Pet != null ? x.Pet.Name : "");
```

Comment: How about replacing `x.Pet != null ? x.Pet.Name : ""` with the terser (and less susceptible to typos) null coalescing operator? `x.Pet ?? string.Empty`

Comment: @spender: That would work only if `Pet` implements [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) Interface.

Comment: Oops. Misread the answer. `Pet`s are not (necessarily) strings.

Answer (score 3):

If you want people with no pets to be sorted above those with pets, you can use this:

```
return this.People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Car.Name)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Pet == null ? string.Empty : x.Pet.Name);
```

If you're going to be doing many sort operations involving pets, you could make your own `PetComparer` class that inherits from `Comparer<Pet>`, like this:

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class PetComparer : Comparer<Pet> // 
{
    public override int Compare(Pet x, Pet y)
    {
        if (x == null) return -1; // y is considered greater than x
        if (y == null) return 1; // x is considered greater than y
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
```

Now, your query would look like this:

```
return this.People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Car.Name)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Pet, new PetComparer());
```

Note: this will do the opposite of the query at the top of this answer--it will sort people without pets to the bottom (within a car name).

Comment: No problem...I did add some additional content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for pets and cars to avoid any additional checks for null in such cases and minimize risk of possible `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Excellent point. I should be doing that. The others answer the question directly though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the null conditional (`?.`) and null coalescing (`??`) operators together you can do this -

```
return this.People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Car.Name)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Pet?.Name ?? string.Empty);
```